# How to get object value of an array by key of my array using extjs?

Tags: arrays, extjs

I've got an array named Array

```
Array = [{id:1, project_name:"Vrindavan", project_phase:"A", project_block:"B", project_unit:"1200.sqt", project_status:"active", project_rent:"52,000", project_maintenance:"mar"},
{id:2, project_name:"Nyanza", project_phase:"B", project_block:"A", project_unit:"1200.sqt", project_status:"active", project_rent:"52,000", project_maintenance:"mar"},
{id:3, project_name:"Rixi", project_phase:"C", project_block:"C", project_unit:"1200.sqt", project_status:"active", project_rent:"52,000", project_maintenance:"mar"}]
```

How to find index of this array where id=2....?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code

```
                 var flag=false;
                 for(var i=0;i< arr.length;i++){
                    var temp=   Ext.Object.getKey(arr[i],2);
                    if(temp=='id'){ 
                         return i;

                      }
                    }
```

I tested it .It is working.Hope this helps you.

Comment: Why loop over the object keys? Just check if it has an id property.